# Spring threads and TaskRejectException when queue is full

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm using Spring to create web application where several users can upload file and with asynchronous task I convert this file.
Now sometime I receive this exception and tomcat goes down:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.task.TaskRejectedException: Executor [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@54a611af[Running, pool size = 10, active threads = 10, queued tasks = 10, completed tasks = 230]] did not accept task: org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1@598b845a
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.submit(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.doSubmit(AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.java:189)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.invoke(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at com.model.ZipAndMat$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5bcfcf5.createZipAndMat(<generated>)
    at com.services.FleetAcquisitionServicesImpl.uploadFiles(FleetAcquisitionServicesImpl.java:95)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@5a47368c rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@54a611af[Running, pool size = 10, active threads = 10, queued tasks = 10, completed tasks = 230]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2047)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1369)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.submit(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:281)
    ... 87 more
```

How can I manage this problem? I thought to increase queue size and when it is full the other task should wait until queue has a free slot.
Thanks

Comment: Parallelism & queue length are configurable (I think: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-executor-usage ) But the broader question is: is your server able to handle that many requests at once and whatever the client is, can it wait longer? What is causing you to hit the limit? Is your server limited in bandwidth or disk io? More queue length should do. When it's slow uploading clients on the other hand and you have more server capacity, add more threads (and probably more queue anyway)

Comment: Server is managed by another company I know the cpu is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v2 @ 3.00GHz and it has 8 GB of ram. I think that the size of 10 is few, what do you think?
User task are asynchronous so they wait only for file upload

Comment: Yes 10 is very little, even for a tiny server. You have to monitor your server and see where it becomes too much to find good values. Especially for thread count. Queue length can probably be in the thousands without issues for the server because (when done right) queue items only consume a tiny bit of memory (and a socket - those can run out too btw).

Comment: Spring doesn't allow automatic queue size?

Comment: Java doesn't have automatic queue sizes. Either completely unbound queues or ones with fixed limits, see "Queuing" section in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: I read Spring and Oracle docs, now I have setted   executor.setCorePoolSize(10);executor.setMaxPoolSize(100);executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
I don't understand the problem if I set unbounded queues

Comment: Unbound Queues can result in an out of memory error instead of a rejected execution exception because no computer has unlimited resources. With servers you typically want to have a limit so that your process does not crash. Ps: `executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler()` is the place to set a strategy for the case the queue is full.

Answer (score 1):

You must not use taskexecutor if your task size exceeds your queue size. Change your method.
For example, write your all request into a permanent store (database, or file etc.) and create a job reads from the store and executes in the manner of sequential processing.